# Assigning values to a sympy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sympy

How to assign values to the SymPy array?

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.tensor.array.expressions import ArraySymbol
from sympy import Array
import numpy as np

F = ArraySymbol("f", (3, 2, 4))  
print(F.shape)
print(F.as_explicit())
for i in range (3):
  for j in range (2):
    for k in range (4):
      F[i,j,k] = 10
      print(F[i,j,k])
```

After executing the above code, I am getting the following error:
TypeError: 'ArraySymbol' object does not support item assignment.

Is their any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Most SymPy expressions are immutable. You probably want to use `F = sympy.Array.zeros(3, 2, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy offers literal and symbolic containers, e.g. Array and ArraySymbol; Matrix MatrixSymbol. The symbols are for manipulating expressions in general where the exact values are not the focus. Thus, one of the things you can't do with the Symol form is assign values to the individual elements. You can only do that with the literal version of the container, and you can do it at instantiation like this:

```py
shape = (3,2,4)
F = Array([10]*prod(shape), shape)
```